# Using InventorServer.MeasureTools in an AppBundle uploaded to Autodesk Platform Services

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I have an Inventor plugin written in C#. One of the lines is `MeasureTools MT = App.MeasureTools;`, where `App` is an `InventorServer` object. However, when I upload it as an AppBundle to APS, I get the following error when trying to run a WorkItem:

```
[10/02/2023 15:04:34]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : SamplePlugin .dll : Processing failed. System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))
[10/02/2023 15:04:34]    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
[10/02/2023 15:04:34]    at Inventor.InventorServerObject.get_MeasureTools()
[10/02/2023 15:04:34]    at SamplePlugin.SampleAutomation..ctor(PartDocument partDoc) in Path/To/Plugin/SampleAutomation.cs:line 112
[10/02/2023 15:04:34]    at ClassifyExtrusionFeaturesPlugin.PluginEntryPoint.RunWithArguments(Document doc, NameValueMap map) in Path/To/Plugin/PluginEntryPoint.cs:line 81
```

Is MeasureTools not supported in APS?

I have tried to run the plugin locally as an addin in my local Inventor app. I use the exact same code, including `InventorServer` objects instead of `Application` objects, etc. It works fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That object has **dependency** on **UI libraries** that are not available in **Inventor Server** - this is not **Design Automation**, but **Inventor Server** specific, i.e. would be the same if you tried to use it from a **Vault Job Processor** that uses **Inventor Server** 
(**Configurator 360** had similar limitations: "iLogic Measure functions are not available." - https://help.autodesk.com/view/CFG360/ENU/?guid=GUID-96EA0CAA-73BB-42C2-94D8-73CC76791DC7)

What you could do is use the underlying functions instead:

```
instead of ...
  ThisServer.MeasureTools.GetMinimumDistance(workPoint1, workPoint2)
... you could do
  workPoint1.Point.DistanceTo(workPoint2.Point)

instead of ...  
  ThisServer.MeasureTools.GetMinimumDistance(workAxis1, workPoint1)
... you could do
  workAxis1.Line.DistanceTo(workPoint1.Point)

etc
```